# Animate elements with different heights to grow the same speed in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I have several divs with different heights that I want to grow to show the full height when clicked. I'm using `animation` with `to` and `from` `max-height`. The problem is that say the hightest div has a full height of 500 px and the smallest 60 px. They both grow but at the same speed making the smaller one more or less just pop open since it's not that high (but continue to grow 'invisably' in the background) and the bigger one growing normaly. Using Javascript, it that matters.

Using this code:

```
    .growRow {
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: grow;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    }

@keyframes grow {
    from {
        max-height: 0;
    }
    to {
        max-height: 500px;
    }
}
```

Bonus question: if I don't know the height of my highest div, is there a way to make my code take care of that? `Auto` is, as far at I''ve gathered, out of the question.

Comment: Have you considered using `scaleY(0)`? There's not much to do with CSS when you can't really know the current height of the element.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the divs contain text, so scale it probably not a good option. @EliyaCohen

Answer (score 0):

Not without using JS... change your CSS to:

```
.growRow {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px; /* or wathever the start height should be */
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.growRow.open {
    height: auto;
}
.no-transition {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Then (using jQuery) in Vanilla JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.growRow').on('click', function () {
        var $growRow = $(this);
        $growRow.addClass('no-transition').addClass('open');
        var newHeight = $growRow.height();
        $growRow.removeClass('open').removeClass('no-transition');
        setTimeout(function ($growRow, newHeight) {
            $growRow.once('transitionend', function () {
                $(this).css('height', '');
            }).css('height', newHeight + 'px');
        }, 0, $growRow, newHeight);
    });
});
```

Haven't tested it though... Let me know if it works!